# Draw one ggplot violinplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a simple violinplot instead of a boxplot

For boxplot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=my_continuous_var)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

If I try:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=my_continuous_var)) +
  geom_violin()
```

I get this error:

! `stat_ydensity()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y

I see the 'y' defined in 'aes' when I try to create various violinplot grouped by n anorother variable:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, factor(cyl))) +
  geom_violin()
```

But that's not my case. Only need one.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: @Sotos That's it! Please post it as an answer, so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it needs you to specify both axis, you can just define a single group for all `mpg` (or any numeric variable you want to plot), i.e.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg , y = 'All_mpg')) +
     geom_violin()
```

[image]

You can even leave it blank,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg , y = '')) +
     geom_violin()
```